# R cannot be resolved to a variable (Android)

Tags: java, android, xml

I have tried every possible solution and I am still given this error. I understand that I must have all the correct xml files, in lowercase, which I do, but they are still not recognized. I have also tried removing `android.R` and importing `my.package.r` etc. But nothing is working.

Here are the two .java files that are given the errors;

Errors given on lines 18, 25, 26, 27, 28.

```
package androidChat;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class addassignment extends Activity {

DBAdapter db = new DBAdapter(this);

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.add);

}

public void addAssignment(View v) {
    Log.d("test", "adding");
    // get data from form
    EditText nameTxt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTitle);
    EditText dateTxt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editDuedate);
    EditText courseTxt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editCourse);
    EditText notesTxt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editNotes);

    db.open();
    long id = db.insertRecord(nameTxt.getText().toString(), dateTxt
            .getText().toString(), courseTxt.getText().toString(), notesTxt
            .getText().toString());
    db.close();

    nameTxt.setText("");
    dateTxt.setText("");
    courseTxt.setText("");
    notesTxt.setText("");
    Toast.makeText(addassignment.this, "Assignment Added",
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}

public void viewAssignments(View v) {
    Intent i = new Intent(this, AssignmentTracker.class);
    startActivity(i);
 }

}
```

And;
Errors given on lines 31 and 33.

```
package androidChat;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class AssignmentTracker extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */

// DBAdapter db = new DBAdapter(this);

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Button addBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.add);
    addBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(AssignmentTracker.this,
                    addassignment.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });

    try {
        String destPath = "/data/data/" + getPackageName()
                + "/databases/AssignmentDB";
        File f = new File(destPath);
        if (!f.exists()) {
            CopyDB(getBaseContext().getAssets().open("mydb"),
                    new FileOutputStream(destPath));
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // DBAdapter db = new DBAdapter(this);

    // ---add an assignment---
    /*
     * db.open(); long id = db.insertRecord("Hello World", "2/18/2012",
     * "DPR 224", "First Android Project"); id =
     * db.insertRecord("Workbook Exercises", "3/1/2012", "MAT 100",
     * "Do odd numbers"); db.close();
     */

    // ---get all Records---
    /*
     * db.open(); Cursor c = db.getAllRecords(); if (c.moveToFirst()) { do {
     * DisplayRecord(c); } while (c.moveToNext()); } db.close();
     */

    /*
     * //---get a Record--- db.open(); Cursor c = db.getRecord(2); if
     * (c.moveToFirst()) DisplayRecord(c); else Toast.makeText(this,
     * "No Assignments found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); db.close();
     */

    // ---update Record---
    /*
     * db.open(); if (db.updateRecord(1, "Hello Android", "2/19/2012",
     * "DPR 224", "First Android Project")) Toast.makeText(this,
     * "Update successful.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); else
     * Toast.makeText(this, "Update failed.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
     * db.close();
     */

    /*
     * //---delete a Record--- db.open(); if (db.deleteRecord(1))
     * Toast.makeText(this, "Delete successful.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
     * else Toast.makeText(this, "Delete failed.",
     * Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); db.close();
     */
}

private class DBAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;

    // private ArrayList<>

    @Override
    public int getCount() {

        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int arg0) {

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int arg0) {

        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int arg0, View arg1, ViewGroup arg2) {

        return null;
    }

}

public void CopyDB(InputStream inputStream, OutputStream outputStream)
        throws IOException {
    // ---copy 1K bytes at a time---
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int length;
    while ((length = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
        outputStream.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }
    inputStream.close();
    outputStream.close();
}

public void DisplayRecord(Cursor c) {
    Toast.makeText(
            this,
            "id: " + c.getString(0) + "\n" + "Title: " + c.getString(1)
                    + "\n" + "Due Date:  " + c.getString(2),
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

public void addAssignment(View view) {

    Intent i = new Intent("com.pinchtapzoom.addassignment");
    startActivity(i);
    Log.d("TAG", "Clicked");
 }

}
```

Here is my AndroidManifest.xml;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="edu.UTEP.android"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

<application
    android:allowTaskReparenting="false"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity
        android:name="androidChat.AndroidChatApplicationActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="androidChat.AssignmentManager" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".AssignmentTracker"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".addassignment" >
    </activity>
</application>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

</manifest>
```

my res/layout files are as follows;

`add.xml`
`assignment_item.xml`
`assignmentmanager.xml`
`main.xml`

Comment: R.java is not generated when there is some syntax error in xml files. Can you check them and see this is the issue?

Comment: R.java is generated and none of the xml files are giving errors.

Comment: Are you using some resource in xml like image and missed to add to drawable?

Comment: I haven't used any images, although I have noticed that the package name in AndroidManifest.xml is different to the one containing the java files, could this be the problem?

Comment: This is definitely a problem. But that should not be the reason for R.java not being resolved. Align the package name in java files with that on Manifest.xml. Seems like you have done some copy-pasting of classes.

Comment: Which IDE do you use? I had a problem with IntelliJ IDEA after the last update. `R.java` wasn't generated, though the project didn't contain any errors. Rolling back to the previous version helped.

Answer (score 0):

**1)** First of all, try compiling the code. Sometimes the error "R cannot be resolved to a variable" can be solved only by compiling the code for the first time.

**2)** May be the problem is with your package name. It shows `package androidChat;`
It should be something like `package com.example.exampleapp;`

Try posting your remaining xml files too. May be that can help me solve your problem.

**Update:** In your first .java file, why don't you initialize your EditText's in onCreate() method.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem, I had to change the package names to match the one in the manifest.xml, it seemed to fix the problem straight away. Thanks for the help.